# Scaling images CSS

Tags: css, image, slider, nivo-slider

I'm using the Nivo Slider and all the images are the same "height/Width" 766x400 but when viewing the slider in Firefox it up-scales everything to a masive 1,333px × 696px.

The interesting thing,when you do a split screen in the browser everything looks fine but full screen everything is blown up.

I'm wondering what CSS code I should be using to fix this issue

I would post my whole "code" but the images are related to my business and I'm not really sure.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a dummy/temporary images to be safe, others would like to see the code you've done

Comment: Hi thanks I just replaced my original images with the demo ones from the Nivo slider.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by inline styles set by Nivo Slider, but it's hard to tell what the cause can be with example CSS/markup.

However the basics for responsive images is to make sure the `width` (or, often preferably, the `max-width`) is set to `100%` and that the `height` is set to `auto`. If there's inline CSS that will override your own CSS so you may either need to add `!important` to those rules or edit the plugin files for Nivo Slider and remove the printing of inline styles.

So basically, try this (but you may want to use a more specific selector and you shouldn't use `!important` unless it's *absolutely* necessary):

```
img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,how can I send you my code? I tried to post it here but stackoverflow won't allow it.

Comment: Put it on a jsfiddle or similar and link to it.

Comment: I have never even seen a program like that and not sure even how to link things to yourself Nils. It would be best If I could just email a detailed code,my business email is info@sos-boardz.com I personal didn't think using stack overflow was this hard.